# Is there any way to tell the linker to ignore DT_SONAME when loading a shared object?

Tags: c, linux, linker

`man ld` says:

> -soname=name
>        When creating an ELF shared object, set the internal DT_SONAME field to the specified name.  When an executable is linked with a
>   shared object which has a DT_SONAME field, then when the executable is
>   run the dynamic linker will attempt to load the shared object
>   specified by the DT_SONAME field rather than the using the file name
>   given to the linker.

Can the second half of this statement be overridden? In other words, can when running an executable can you force the linker to ignore the DT_SONAME of external shared libraries and instead use file names only?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> In other words, can when running an executable can you force the linker to ignore the DT_SONAME of external shared libraries and instead use file names only?

No.

First, the linker is not involved in the running of the executable, the *loader* (also known as the dynamic linker) is. The loader is a completely separate program, and usually shares no code, and is totally different from the linker.

Second, after the linker is done, the filename that was used to link the executable is not recorded *anywhere* (only the `DT_SONAME` is recorded). So even if the loader wanted to use the original filename, there is no way for it to find out what it was.

That said, you *could* change the string in the `.dynstr` section of the executable that records the `DT_SONAME`. If the string is (say) `foobar.so.1`, and you binary edit it to be `barfoo.so` instead, then the loader will look for `barfoo.so` (using its usual shared library search rules) instead of `foobar.so.1`. The only limitation here is that the new name is not longer than the old one (or else you'll corrupt some other string).

It's also possible to replace the `.dynstr` section with a new one with longer strings (and replace `foobar.so.1` with `/full/path/to/libsomething.so`), but this transformation is much harder to perform correctly.

Comment: Excellent answer. Thanks.